# User prompt interrupting loop - how to auto-respond?

Tags: r, loops, command-prompt, readline

Sometimes functions prompt users for input like so:

```
foo = function() {
  cat("Hit [enter]")
  readline()
}
```

This makes using the function in a loop impractical since in every iteration the user is asked to provide input before the loop continues:

```
> lapply(1:10, function(i) {
+   invisible(foo())
+ })
Hit [enter]
```

What's an efficient way to suppress that behaviour so that the function is still usable in a loop?

Comment: Most(?) functions offer some sort of escape hatch to prevent interactive prompts, if present. Without further information, I recommend consulting the offending function's documentation. Sometimes, a package will have a global escape hatch in the form of a global option.

Comment: That was quick - thanks @smingerson. I guess a challenge to that is that in some cases there are no obvious escape hatches. I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62291310/problems-in-using-varxirf) question earlier and it's not obvious how to escape the command prompts of the `VARXirf` function. Looking at the package [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MTS/MTS.pdf) there aren't any clear hints either. So I'm wondering if there's a straight-forward fix for such cases?

Comment: From a brief glance at the [source](https://github.com/d-/MTS/blob/aa1ead3f1d3b30f8a92fdb4103f98c7b94042bd0/R/MTS.R), it appears that only readline is causing the problem. The documentation for readline says it is only for interactive use, so presumably it does not pause the script if you run it non-interactively. That might be the solution.